# Wamp server local

Tags: wamp

I downloaded WAMP server last version (PHP and Apache and MySQL ) and I have a problem. When I am on localhost all works fine, but when I access my public IP from a browser, it says:

```
You don't have permission to access / on this server.
Apache/2.4.23 (Win64) PHP/5.6.25 Server at 95********* Port 80
```

How can I fix this?

already fixed with:

```
# Virtual Hosts
#

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot c:/wamp64/www
    <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/">
        Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

#
```